# Heroku console not loading file in /lib?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm not being able to require a file under `/lib` on Heroku console. Any idea why?

This is in my local machine

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require "folder/file.rb"
 => true
```

This is on Heroku console (Cedar)

```
irb(main):057:0> require "folder/file.rb"
=> false
```

Comment: Does it work with `require "./folder/file.rb"`?

Comment: It does, thanks. Actually it works with `./lib/folder/file.rb`. You can try that as an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the question's comments, it worked with `require './folder/file.rb'`.
Note the `./` before the file path.